# Is there a "test room" for Twilio Programmable Video?

Tags: twilio

I'm building a web app that uses Twilio Programmable Video to connect users.  Works great on all my computers and browsers!  When I tested it with 12 people this morning I got a 40% success rate.  "I couldn't see any video" was the most common response.  Browser permissions, browser versions... who knows why.

Does Twilio have a recommended flow for allowing users to test the video features?  Perhaps a test room with an always-on video stream.  I could test `getUserMedia` myself, but I'd prefer some sort of end-to-end test that ensures when a user is ready to connect to a real person, everything is good to go.

Zoom has this feature in their app.  I realize it's not a fair comparison, but this feature has reduced the time spent dealing with "video's not working!" tech issues at the start of a meeting.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly today.

Twilio has a more exhaustive testing tool located here, https://networktest.twilio.com/.

Comment: That is a very cool dashboard, but... not exactly what I'm looking for to give my users comfort that their video calls will work!  Thanks.